# PHP-FPM conf location option when compiling php

Tags: configuration, php-fpm

I'm compiling PHP from source. I would like to set the location that PHP-FPM looks for it's config file.

Apparently this option should be set via the configure option:

```
--with-fpm-conf=/etc/php/php-fpm.conf
```

According to http://php-fpm.org/wiki/Configuration_File

However using this option on PHP5.5.0 gives the error `configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-fpm-conf`

How do I set where PHP-FPM should look for it's conf file when compiling from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not present since a long time. I believe it was available when config was still in XML format.

Config file location is passed during startup, see startup script located in `sapi/fpm/init.d.php-fpm` in php source directory.